# How to connect to database at MySQL using LUA?

Tags: mysql, database, lua, mysql-connector

I try to connect to MySQL using LUA however an error occurs such as:

**Module 'luasql.mysql' not found:
no field package.preload['luasql.mysql']**

```
luasql = require "luasql.mysql"

env = assert (luasql.mysql())

con=assert(env:connect("db_name","username","pass","host",port))
```

How can I connect successfully to MySQL database?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using lua-jdbc ?
Try `luarocks install luasql-jdbc`

Then install lua-mysql `luarocks install luasql-mysql`

Run again.

Check the Project: https://github.com/keplerproject/luasql

Comment: It outputs this when I try: Installing https://luarocks.org/luasql-mysql-2.3.5-1.rockspec
Error: Could not find header file for MYSQL
  No file mysql.h in /usr/local/include
  No file mysql.h in /usr/include
  No file mysql.h in /include
You may have to install MYSQL in your system and/or pass MYSQL_DIR or MYSQL_INCDIR to the luarocks command.

Comment: Try this: `luarocks install luasql-mysql MYSQL_INCDIR=/usr/local/path/to/your/mysql/include/mysql`